# With erc-1155 can you mint tokens on the fly with parameterized name and supply?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, nft, erc-721, erc-1155

The erc-1155 contract would have various token types. Users would be able to request minting (contract owner would mind the tokens on their behalf) of any type available on the contract but they would decide on the token name and supply.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

Yes, it is possible.